# Error on iOS Simulator when debugging MonoTouch - 3.2 SDK error when only 4.3 installed?

Tags: sqlite, mono, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, monodevelop

When attempting to debug a working iOS app on a new Lion 10.7.1/MonoTouch 4.0.7/MonoDevelop 2.6/XCode 4.1 (4B110) install, I get an error regarding libsqlite3:

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
>   : parsing file    : /Users/ben/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/BB35EEFB-5700-466F-BD50-FF296D308FE6/Documents/databasefile
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I checked, this file does not appear to exist:

> ls
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/
>   ls:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/:
>   No such file or directory

I only have the iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk installed. Anyone have any ideas what would be attempting to hook this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that is [fixed](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=240) in MonoTouch 4.2. There is a [workaround](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52) if you cannot update immediately.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Will wait to update, but creating a duplicate of the 4.3 directory to provide a 3.2 worked just fine.